# Using Textarea Within Swiper Slider (Disable Touch Events)

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, slide, swiper.js

I'm using the [idangerous "Swiper" slider](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php). One of my slides has a textarea in it that is causing issues. Everything is OK on the desktop, but on mobile when entering text in the textarea, Swiper seems to reinitialize and return to the first slide.

As this happens on mobile only, I am guessing it is related to one of the touch events firing in the text area.

As suggested in another post I have applied:

```
$('textarea#text_area_name').on('touchstart mousedown', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

This didn't solve the problem, so I extended it to include all touch events. And then all parents (until the swiper wrapper). Still with no success.

I have tried using alerts to show which touch events are firing. But I can't see the event that is fired immediately before the before swiper resets.

Does anyone have any experience of using a textarea within the idangerous swiper slider? Or any ideas on what event may be causing the issue and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when you write the question down the answer becomes clearer...

I was reinitializing Swiper on window.resize to manage the dynamic sizing. The resize event was getting triggered by the textarea on mobile devices. Maybe this is due to the soft keyboard popping up. Anyway, removing the reinitialize on resize solved the problem.